# mysql replace select union malfunction

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Assume: tables have the same structure StockID, Date, Time, Price, Volume; Now, `H0001I` Volume = 15000,`H0002I` Volume = 40000,`H0003I` Volume = 12000;

So, I run:

```
REPLACE table1 SELECT * FROM (
SELECT StockID, Date, Time, Price, Volume from H0001I 
UNION SELECT StockID, Date, Time, Price, Volume from H0002I         
UNION SELECT StockID, Date, Time, Price, Volume from H0003I
               +... more than 70 rows ...+
               ) all_tables WHERE all_tables.Date = CURDATE();
```

`table1`should return StockID, Date, Time, Price, Volume

However, `table1`'s volume got problem randomly. Sometimes `H0001I` got 15000000 rather than 15000, sometimes `H0002I` got 40000000 rather than 40000, etc. It randomly happens on different rows (usually less than 3 rows) and it would be fixed after the next run. I have checked the volume from respective table immediately but I cannot find any problem. I know float type of the variables could get troubles but I don't know if I change the type of Volume could fix the problem. OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: can you create a minimal example with a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0)?

Comment: 'REPLACE makes sense only if a table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html, please add your table definition

Comment: @P.Salmon The primary key is StockID.